# R: Access private functons inside a package

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to access private functions inside an R package. I'm sorry if "private" is not exactly the correct word, but hopefully an example can clear up any confusion.

I'm working with the R package hdi ([link to CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdi/index.html)). In the hdi package, there is a function called multi.split. I can access to function body of multi.split with:

```
mult.split
```

or

```
hdi::multi.split
```

When I do that, I see that multi.split calls a function called aggregate.ci. I can see that it's in the Namespace of the function:

```
ls(getNamespace("hdi"), all.names=TRUE)
```

I want to see the body of the function aggregate.ci, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: `getAnywhere("aggregate.ci")`?

Comment: That does it.Thank you.